# Enviar datos al servidor mediante Ajax usando Promesas de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promesas

Dado que las Promesas de Javascript prometen mucho. Una de las cosas que me gustaría saber es **cómo hacer una petición Ajax mediante promesas**, en puro Javascript, sin tener que pasar por librerías de terceros.

Se trataría de una petición que maneje adecuadamente el éxito o el fracaso de la petición hecha, indicando el resultado obtenido o bien un mensaje de error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La nueva [`API Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) permite realizar llamadas "AJAX" (`Request`) e implementa `Promises` por defecto.

Ejemplo de uso:

```js
function get(method) {
  var url = document.getElementById("datos").value;

  fetch(url, {
    method: method
  }).then(function(response) {
    response.json().then(function(object) {
      console.log("¡Correcto!", object);
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("!Hubo un error!", error);
  });
}
```

```html
Introduzca URL de un servicio REST y pulse Enviar:<br />
<input id="datos" type="text" value="https://api.github.com" size="33" />
<input type="button" onclick="get('GET')" value="Enviar..." />
```

Mas info:

[* David Walsh - fech API](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)
[* Google Developers - Introduction to fetch()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)
[* Github - fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: +1 No conocía esa API. Y el código se simplifica bastante. Aunque la doc dice que todavía no es compatible con varios navegadores.

Comment: @A.Cedano, si bien es cierto que la nueva `API fetch` no es compatible con varios navegadores, hay que tener en cuenta que [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise#Compatibilidad_de_navegadores) tampoco. Por suerte para todos, se pueden encontrar `polyfills`

Answer (score 3):

Este sería un ejemplo de función de llamada a Ajax, usando Promesas.

Con nuestra función `myAjax()` podemos hacer peticiones vía ajax y obtener la respuesta, o el código de error, de forma transparente, sin necesidad de librerías como jQuery.

Según se indica en el enlace de más abajo:

> Las API anteriores se actualizarán para usar promesas y si es posible,
>   se hará de forma que sean compatibles con versiones anteriores.
>   XMLHttpRequest es una gran candidata.

Lo cual quiere decir que las llamadas a Ajax mediante Promises será mucho más fácil en un futuro. Mientras eso llega, podemos usar una función como esta, pasándole a la función en parámetro el método (`GET, POST`)  y la url del servicio REST, API, o un archivo php, json u otro de nuestras aplicaciones.

```js
function myAjax(method, url) {
  // Devolver una nueva Promise.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Hacer lo usual de XHR 
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open(method, url);

    req.onload = function() {
      // Esto es llamado incluso cuando ocurre error 404 etc
      // Verificar el status
      if (req.status == 200) {
        // Resolver la Promise con el texto de respuesta
        resolve(req.response);
        console.log(req.response);
      } else {
        // De lo contrario, rechazar con el texto del estatus
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    // Manejar errores de red
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    // Hacer la petición
    req.send();
  });
}

function get(method) {
  var url = document.getElementById("datos").value;
  myAjax(method, url).then(function(response) {
    console.log("¡Correcto!", response);
  }, function(error) {
    console.error("!Hubo un error!", error);
  })
}
```

```html
Introduzca URL de un servicio REST y pulse Enviar:<br />
<input id="datos" type="text" value="https://api.github.com" size="33" />
<input type="button" onclick="get('GET')" value="Enviar..." />
```

---

#### Enlaces

- [Promesas de JavaScript: introducción](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises?hl=es#promesas_en_xmlhttprequest)
- [esSO: ¿Qué es una promesa en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64265/29967)