# Pasar variables de javascript a php y viceversa

Tags: javascript

Como puedo pasar variables a php desde javascript sin usar ni jquery ni ajax

Usando jquery y ajax para pasar variables seria algo como esto:

```
<script>
var nombre = $("#nombreVal").val();
var apellido_paterno = $("#apellido_paternoVal").val();
var apellido_materno = $("#apellido_maternoVal").val();
var correo = $("#correoVal").val();
var telefono = $("#telefonoVal").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../includes/acciones/cliente/insert.php",
    data: "nombre=" + nombre + "&apellido_paterno=" + apellido_paterno 
          + "&apellido_materno=" + apellido_materno 
          + "&correo=" + correo + "&telefono=" + telefono, 
    success: function(data)
    {   
      if(data > 0)
        window.location.reload(true);
      else
        alert("Error al registrar al cliente");
    }           
});
</script>
```

Pero esto como lo puedo hacer usando solo javascript??

Comment: Jorge bienvenido. Creo que debes aclarar tu pregunta. No es lo mismo decir: ***sin usar jQuery y Ajax***  que decir ***sin usar [ni]  jQuery ni Ajax***. Más simple: ¿no quieres usar Ajax de ninguna de las maneras? Si es así, puedes pasar las variables por PHP mismo, pero debes saber que a cada paso de variable tendrás que recargar la página. Lo mejor para esto es usar Ajax.

Comment: @A.Cedano yo pienso que lo mejor para este caso es usar ajax, pero últimamente he visto varios artículos que dicen que jquery ya esta dejando de ser usado y ahora se esta empezando a usar javascript puro porque actualmente la mayoría de los exploradores ya son compatibles con este lenguaje, es por eso que quiero saber como pasar variables a php usando solo javascript

Comment: Ah ya, es que no entendía bien si querías usar Ajax o no. Pero, me temo que tu pregunta es  [duplicada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25798/cómo-realizar-una-llamada-ajax-sin-bibliotecas) de [duplicada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79849/29967). Creo que revisando las respuestas a esas dos preguntas encontrarás varias formas de hacer peticiones Ajax prescindiendo de jQuery. Y estoy de acuerdo contigo. Hay algunas páginas que trata sobre esto, como por ejemplo [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com)

Comment: Posible duplicado de **[¿Cómo realizar una llamada AJAX sin bibliotecas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25798/c%c3%b3mo-realizar-una-llamada-ajax-sin-bibliotecas)**. Ver también las respuestas a la pregunta: [Enviar datos al servidor mediante Ajax sin usar librerías tales como jQuery -duplicada-](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79849/29967)

Answer (score 0):

con jquery ajax:

```
   <script>
/// combierte todo los campos dentro de  <form></form> a formato url
    var datos = $( "form" ).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/includes/acciones/cliente/insert.php",
    data: datos, 
    success: function(data)
    {   
      if(data > 0)
        window.location.reload(true);
      else
        alert("Error al registrar al cliente");
    }           
});
</script>
```

sin jquery:

```
<form action="http://localhost/includes/acciones/cliente/insert.php" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="nombre"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="apellido">
  etc....
</form>
```